# AIOHTTP with Graphql: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'resolve'. Why this problem?

Tags: python, graphql, aiohttp

I'm following the **GraphQL-core 3** documentation. Why this problem?

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
from graphql import (
    graphql, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLField, GraphQLString)


async def resolve_hello(obj, info):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'world'

schema = GraphQLSchema(
    query=GraphQLObjectType(
        name='RootQueryType',
        fields={
            'hello': GraphQLField(
                GraphQLString,
                resolve=resolve_hello)
        }))


async def main():
    query = '{ hello }'
    print('Fetching the result...')
    result = await graphql(schema, query)
    print(result)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

After running the script, the terminal returns the following error

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 16, in <module>
    resolve=resolve_hello)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'resolve'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with graphql version. For example on version `0.5.3` I got the same issue as you.

```
from graphql import (
    GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLField, GraphQLString)

schema = GraphQLSchema(
    query=GraphQLObjectType(
        name='RootQueryType',
        fields={
            'hello': GraphQLField(
                GraphQLString,
                resolve=lambda obj, info: 'world')
        }))
>>> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'resolve'
```

Just changed to version 3 or higher.

```
pip install "graphql-core>=3"
```